# “Неверный пароль” при авторизации.Что может быть?

Tags: php, auth

Уже не знаю что делать и куда обратиться за помощью. `var_dump()` молчит. Спасите помогите, пожалуйста, товарищи.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "include/auth.php",
  data: "email=" + auth_email + "&pass=" + auth_pass + "&rememberme=" + auth_rememberme,
  dataType: "html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    if (data == 'yes_auth') {
      location.reload();
    } else {
      $("#message-auth").slideDown(400);
      $(".auth-loading").hide();
      $("#button-auth").show();
    }
  }
});


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  include('db_connect.php');
  include('../functions/functions.php');

  $email = clear_string($_POST["email"]);

  $pass = md5(clear_string($_POST["pass"]));
  $pass = strrev($pass);
  $pass = strtolower("9nm2rv8q" . $pass . "2yo6z");

  if ($_POST["rememberme"] == "yes") {
    setcookie('rememberme', $email . '+' . $pass, time() + 3600 * 24 * 31, "/");
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE email = '$email' AND pass = '$pass'");
  If (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['auth'] = 'yes_auth';
    $_SESSION['auth_pass'] = $row["pass"];
    $_SESSION['auth_email'] = $row["email"];
    $_SESSION['auth_name'] = $row["name"];

    echo 'yes_auth';
  } else {
    echo 'no_auth';
  }
}
```

Comment: У меня такая же фигня, но данные из формы собирал так: `filter = $(".live-search").serialize();`

Comment: Здравствуйте,вы решили проблему?Уже неделю на нее потратил! :с

Comment: не понятно как вы используете `var_dump()`, если он молчит. напишите `var_dump("SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE email = '$email' AND pass = '$pass'");` перед mysqli_query, выведется запрос в бд, откройте phpmyadmin, и смотрите в данные, почему по этому запросу ничего не возвращается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не будьте заложниками собственной глупости,так же как и я,ребята!Неделю потратил на то,чтобы понять,что пишу email полностью "hoho@gmail.com",а нужно  вот так "hoho" :D
Так же,если session_start ругается,то измените output_buffering = On на output_buffering = On  в файле php.ini!